# Running RInside example produces Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT. Why?

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

After installing the RInside package from within R I tried to compile and run the examples provided. Changing directory to `$R_HOME/library\RInside\examples\standard` the command

`make -f Makefile.win rinside_sample0`

nicely produced the executable `rinside_sample0.exe`
Running it under Windows a Popup with the fatal error message *"unable to initialize the JIT"* appeared.

The error occurred in R-4.03 Windows 10 but not in R-4.22 Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: That will be hard to analyse or reproduce for anyone but you.  RInside has been on CRAN for many years and hence been tested by CRAN rather regularly as well as used by other people.  I have heard _that_ line you quote here.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. Problem solved: The windows environment variable ```R_HOME``` was necessary to be set. With this, the error vanished.